# Responsive flexbox - change margins from horizontal to vertical after wrapping?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I have a simple layout concept that can be summarized by this picture:
[image: before wrapping]

This can be easily achieved using `flexbox`. As you can see, the div #1 and div #3 touch the borders of their container. Also, the margin between div #1 and div #2 is equal to the margin between div #2 and div #3. It can be done with:

```
.inner-div{
   margin-left:10px;
}

.inner-div:first-child{
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

Now, let say that the viewport's width decreases. I want those divs to wrap to form a nice column. And I'd like them to look like this:

[image: desirable]

But if those divs retain their horizontal margin configuration, they look something like this instead:

[image: undesirable]

Which, as you can guess, is undesirable.

How to change margins for those inner divs when their container is so narrow that they get "wrapped"? Is there a way to write a conditional rule that would apply only to "wrapped" divs? Or am I missing the point and the solution is very obvious and I just overlooked that part of `flex-box` capabilities?
I'd like to see a solution that would not involve predicting what container/screen width would case the layout to change from row to column, because I think that is the most maintainable option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can absolutely use negative margins to achieve that.

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/287vW/

If you don't even bother removing the margin from the first element but leave it, and globally reduce the margin of the container, you will end up with a consistent result.

Let's assume you have the following structure:

```
<div class="margin">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box one"></div>
        <div class="box two"></div>
        <div class="box three"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can apply these styles:

```
.margin {
    border:3px solid #000000;
}

.container {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    margin:-10px 0 0 -10px;
}

.box {
    height:100px;
    background-color:#555555;
    margin:10px 0 0 10px;
    flex-grow:1;
    min-width:300px;
}
```

Even though we keep all margins on the elements, the negative margin of the container removes them.

Consult the JS Fiddle mentioned above for the result.

I'm sure this can be achieved with one div less, but I think you can figure that out yourself now.

Hope it helped :)

P.S.: If you want to know more about negative margins, see this article on smashing mag: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/

Answer (score 0):

yes, have a look into [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).

Also, i made a little [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54gYx/1/) where you can see it in action at a very simple level. 
Just move the vertical bar to the right and you'll see the media query do its magic.

```
@media (max-width: 200px){
    .inner-div {
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
        float: none;
    }

    #one{
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    }

    #three {
        margin: 0px;
   }
}
```

If you take away the media query in the jsfiddle it will look just you described.

Comment: I think that this solution is too inflexible. The sole point of using `flex-box` for me is not to worry about media queries and let the layout dictate the flow within a `flex-box`ed div. With your solution I'd have to predict what screen sizes would influence inner divs. And the fact that choosing a right breakpoint depending on various factors (such as viewport width, layout, length of text within other divs) is so cumbersome makes this solution very hard to maintain. I'm looking for a more flexible and maintainable solution.